# Why, when I make an http call, do I get an error saying my url is not a string?

Tags: javascript, http

The config file contains an object:

```
var config = {
  uri: 'https://localhost:1234',
  postcodeTimeoutMillsecs: process.env.POSTCODE_TIMEOUT || 3000
};

module.exports = config;
```

My http call gives me an error saying my must be a string, which I'm pretty sure it is. The console.log tells me I'm passing 'http://localhost:1234', which is what I expect.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const config = require('../config/config');
const defaultHttp = require('axios');
const ono = require('ono');

exports.submitApplication = (data) => {
  console.log('config.uri=');
  console.log(config.uri);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let http = defaultHttp;

    http.options({
      method: 'post',
      url: config.uri,
      data: data,
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    }).then(function (response) {
      resolve(response);
    }).catch(function (error) {
      var submissionErr;
      if (error.type === 'http') {
        // error received from DRSI Communicator
        submissionErr = ono({ status: error.code },
          'Submission failed - ' + error.toString() +
          ' - ' + (error.body.message || error.body.errors.join()));
        console.log(submissionErr);
      } else {
        submissionErr = ono({ status: 503 },
          'Submission failed - internal connectivity problem - ' + error.toString());
      }
      submissionErr.errorType = 'submission-failure';
      reject(submissionErr);
    });
  });
};
```

The full error message is:
message: 'Submission failed - internal connectivity problem - TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object'

Any idea where I’m going wrong?

Comment: What's the content of `../config/config`?

Comment: And what's the output of these 2 lines `console.log('config.uri=');
  console.log(config.uri);`?

Comment: A quick and dirty solution is to typecast to a string `String(config.uri)`. It doesn't fix the problem that is causing the issue, but should at least allow you to run the api

Comment: config.config contains an object with cinfiguration variables, one of which is  uri:  'http://localhost:1234',
The console.log output is  'http://localhost:1234',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using the wrong method.

The argument list for `http.options` is: `axios.options(url[, config])`.

---

```
http.options({
      method: 'post',
      url: config.uri,
      data: data,
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    })
```

should probably be

```
http({
      method: 'post',
      url: config.uri,
      data: data,
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    })
```

or

```
http.post(config.uri, data {
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    })
```

Source:
https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosoptionsurl-config